# Find line that matches a substring, then print THAT line and the following

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am trying to find the line containing string 7KFF_1 in a file. I want to print the line where it's located and the line right after. I tried this but I am not sure where I went wrong

```
awk '/7KFF_1/ { header = $0; next } { print header"\n"$0 }' sample.txt
```

NOTICE! I DON'T want to print the n lines after a match! I would like the current line where the match was made and the line right after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` or `sed` if applicable?

```
grep -A1 '7KFF_1' file
```

will print the line and **1 Line after** as too would

```
sed -n '/7KFF_1/{N;p}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/pattern/,$p' YOUR_FILE | head -2
```

The first part prints all lines after the pattern, then pipe it to `head -2` printing the line containing your pattern AND the following line.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag.  If the flag is set, print the line (to print the line after the match).  Then assign the flag depending on if the current line matches.  Then print if the flag is set (to print the line that matches.)

```
awk 'f; {f = /7KFF_1/}; f' sample.txt
```

You can simplify this to:

```
awk 'f; f = /7KFF_1/' sample.txt
```

but I thought that was a bit too obscure for the initial presentation.